# hook into woocommerce_variation_price_html wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a plugin for woocommerce and came across the hook "woocommerce_variation_price_html" which allows you to hook into the variation prices drop down on single products. So created a quick function to test and have a play:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html' , 'wholesale_variation_price' );
function wholesale_variation_price($term){

 return '';

}
```

The above works nicely and removes all data. However i am trying to add custom meta_data to replace the default values.

So i then did the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html' , 'wholesale_variation_price' );
function wholesale_variation_price($term){

$var_price = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_my_price', true );

 return $var_price;

}
```

This for some reason does not work? Has anyone had any experience working with this hook in woocommerce? There is not much documentation on that hook anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That hook is not for updating price. That one is used for formating output. This one will only change price that user sees. Not the actual price used in cart/order. Also check if get_post_meta returns value.

Comment: Yes i would like to just format the output, the cart / order price is already taken care of. post_meta returns a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already indicated that you can read [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php#L308) about filters for html.
Maybe you have Sale price set for variation? Then in link you can see that there are total of 4 filters. For: price, sale price, free and no price.

This code works

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_html', 10, 2);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_html', 10, 2);
function my_html( $price, $variation ) {
    return woocommerce_price(5);
}
```

Also this one works too. This allows you to modify whole variation. Read in code [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L391)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['price_html'] = woocommerce_price(6);
    return $data;
}
```

Screenshots:

First example

[image: example of first filter]

Second example

[image: example of second filter]

Works like magic!

P.S. you can see prices like this in screenshots because I have design that show them like that.

---

EDIT 2016-09-10

**Version 2.6+**

As woocommerce_price is deprecated in 2.6 then use wc_price for newer versions.

Comment: i didnt know the woocommerce_price() function existed! How can i get specific variation id within this function? i need to get a custom field

Comment: I updated my post. I did mess up smth. Second function fixed. Also in both ways you have variable $variation [or w/e you choose to name it]. In first function as second (2.) variable. And in second function you have third (3.) variable for variation.

Comment: thanks for the update! so how would i target a specific meta_value of _my_price for each variation?

Comment: As `woocommerce_price()` is deprecated, this code is not working anymore… If you could update it, this will be very useful for the community. Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec added edit with comment. Should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Display Price For Variable Product With Same Variations Prices
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', function ($value, $object = null, $variation = null) {
if ($value['price_html'] == '') {
    $value['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>';
}
return $value;}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at WooCommerce source code, I see that [`woocommerce_variation_price_html`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php#L308) is a filter, not an action. I don't know how you managed to get your sample code to work like that... weird.

Try this:

```
function wholesale_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $var_price = get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_my_price', true );
    return $var_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'wholesale_variation_price', 10, 2 )
```

Comment: Think has to same outcome as add_action as far as i can see? Which works, but only updates the price of 1 item from the dropdown.

Comment: I just checked and WordPress function `add_action` is using `add_filter` function, so `add_action` is basically just an alias and they have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to modify the variation prices to show the price for each variation product excluding tax before and including tax after :)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['price_html'] = "<span class='ex-vat-price'>ex. " . woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_excluding_tax()) . "</span><br>";
    $data['price_html'] .= "<span class='inc-vat-price'>inc. " . woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_including_tax()) . "</span>";
    return $data;
}
```