# Woocommerce variation - display with and without tax price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here the current template displaying the price excluding vat and the description I would like to add the price including tax between them it's not working

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
        {{{ data.variation.price_html }}}
    </div>

    <div class="price-vat">
        <!-- Here display price including tax -->
    </div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
        {{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}
    </div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">
        {{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: not familiar with woocommerce. do you have the price stored or could you just calculate it?

Comment: The price is calculated by woocommerce according to the variations selected.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669027/hook-into-woocommerce-variation-price-html-wordpress

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your functions.php :)

It returns the variation price excluding tax before and including tax after. You can edit this function to add wording/styling etc.

You may need to use wc_price instead of woocommerce_price as of WooCommerce Version 2.6+.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['price_html'] = "<span class='ex-vat-price'>ex. " . woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_excluding_tax()) . "</span><br>";
    $data['price_html'] .= "<span class='inc-vat-price'>inc. " . woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_including_tax()) . "</span>";
    return $data;
}
```

Source: I modified the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669027/hook-into-woocommerce-variation-price-html-wordpress).